# Avoiding code duplication for methods (link actions) accessible from multiple scopes

Tags: angularjs

Say I have an index page of records, like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">
    <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="" ng-click="showRecord(record);">View</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="deleteRecord(record);">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And a controller, something like this:

```
app.controller('RecordIndexCtrl', function($scope, RecordResource) {
   $scope.records = RecordResource.query();

   $scope.deleteRecord = function(record) {
       // Code to delete record, set flash, change route etc
   }
});
```

So far that's great. But what if I want to include a Delete link on the View page? or anywhere else in my app outside the scope of that controller?

Comment: Generally, any code that will be shared between different controllers should be put in a service that gets injected into the controllers.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I think what I'm struggling with is in RoR for example anywhere I want a DeleteRecord link, id just place the link. In Angular I have to place the link then make sure the current scope has a method for it, so if I want to place it in the Index list, and also in the Sidebar on the Show page, I have two controllers with methods responsible for deleting the resource. They would arguably do different things after that, so I guess if I wrap it in a service that fixes my concern.